# C# List.AddRange in Parallel.For occur ArgumentException

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, parallel-processing

My code like that.

```
List<MyPanel> list_panel = new List<MyPanel>();
.......
List<string> list_sql = new List<string>();
Parallel.For(0, list_panel.Count, i =>
{
    if (list_panel[i].R == 0)
    {
        list_sql.AddRange(list_panel[i].MakeSqlForSave()); // it returns two string
    }
});
```

But AddRange occur System.ArgumentException sometimes.

I found 'list isn't for multi write'. So I fix it using lock.

```
string[] listLock = new string[2];
Parallel.For(0, list_panel.Count, i =>
{
    if (list_panel[i].R == 0)
    {
        listLock = list_panel[i].MakeSqlForSave();    
        lock(listLock)
            list_sql.AddRange(listLock);
    }
});
```

But it still occur System.ArgumentException that 'Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.' sometimes.

An error occurred in list_sql. If the count is 34, but the IndexOfRangeException occurs when you call list_sql[32] and list_sql[33].

How can I handle it?

Comment: `List<T>` (and especially `List<T>.AddRange`) is not thread-safe.

Comment: Your `lock()` statement is incorrect because it locks on a thread-local object rather than a shared object.

Comment: Is `MyPanel` a WinForms control? If so, this code is unsafe because WinForms controls should only be accessed from the GUI thread.

Comment: You reassign listlock, then lock on it. This makes the lock meaningless as you will have many locks. You don't lock on the variable, you lock on the (new) object it refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ConcurrentBag<T>` as a thread-safe collection [that you can safely append to from multiple threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1.add?view=netframework-4.8):

```
ConcurrentBag<String> result = new ConcurrentBag<String>();

Parallel.For(0, list_panel.Count, i =>
{
    if (list_panel[i].R == 0)
    {
        foreach( String s in list_panel[i].MakeSqlForSave() )
        {
            result.Add( s );
        }
    }
});

List<String> list_sql = result.Select( s => s ).ToList(); // Serialize to a single List<T> after the concurrent operations are complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a dedicated lock for the specific `List`, and use it every time you access this list (for both read and write).

```
List<MyPanel> list_panel = new List<MyPanel>();
List<string> list_sql = new List<string>();
object listSqlLock = new object();
Parallel.For(0, list_panel.Count, i =>
{
    if (list_panel[i].R == 0)
    {
        var sqlCommands = list_panel[i].MakeSqlForSave();
        lock (listSqlLock)
            list_sql.AddRange(sqlCommands);
    }
});
```